# add-to-list 'load-path doesn't seem to work

Tags: emacs, dot-emacs, load-path

Whenever I see some installation instruction for an emacs package it always suggests to use `add-to-list 'load-path` it never works for me. For some reason and I have to use `load-file`. For example, this will not work:

```
(add-to-list 'load-path "~/.emacs.d/jade-mode")
(require 'sws-mode)
(require 'jade-mode)    
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.styl$" . sws-mode))
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.jade$" . sws-mode))
```

but this will work:

```
(load-file "~/.emacs.d/jade-mode/sws-mode.el")
(load-file "~/.emacs.d/jade-mode/jade-mode.el")
(require 'sws-mode)
(require 'jade-mode)
```

anybody can tell me why?
EDIT: I use Carbon Emacs on MAC OS X 10.5

Comment: When you say it "doesn't work," how does it fail? Is it that the `require` calls fail?

Comment: Did you evaluate each expression with eval-buffer or eval-expression? Or put it in your. Emacs file then save and restart?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Perhaps the problem is that the leading tilde ('~') is not expanded when `require` searches the entries in the `load-path` list. Consider using [the `expand-file-name` function](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/elisp/html_node/File-Name-Expansion.html) to prepare your entry for subsequent use by `require`:

```
(add-to-list 'load-path (expand-file-name "jademode" "~/.emacs.d"))
```

or

```
(add-to-list 'load-path (expand-file-name "~/.emacs.d/jademode"))
```

It would help to know which Emacs you're using on which operating system.

Comment: yes, you need to use expand-file-name when adding to load-path.

Answer (score 1):

i'm not 100% sure but i would guess that the list is not instantiated and thus you can't add anything to the load-path list, i just instantiate the list with

```
    (setq load-path (cons (expand-file-name "~/.emacs.d/lisp")
              load-path))
```

Answer (score 1):

The first answer didn't work for me.  Adding the directory path, not individual .el files, worked for me, i.e.:

```
(add-to-list 'load-path (expand-file-name "~/.emacs.d"))
```

Comment: You're correct; but **no one** suggested adding individual .el files to the load-path. Your answer is no different to the accepted answer. Also, [don't put ~/.emacs.d in your load-path](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24791753/324105).

Comment: I misunderstood. I thought jademode means jademode.el but I guess it is a directory name. And thank you for the reference to the other article.

Comment: Ah, that explains it. No, `load-path` is directories only. The source of the confusion might be that when you're `load`ing a specific library, you can (and typically should) omit the extension, and let Emacs choose which one to use.