# Emacs sr-speedbar cannot open loadfile, sr-speedbar

Tags: emacs, editor, elisp

I'm having difficulty following the instructions for installing speedbar on Emacs.

step 1.  Put Lisp:sr-speedbar.el in your load-path, add
        (require 'sr-speedbar)

ok put "sr-speedbar.el" in my load-path. (first of all I am making the assumption my load-path is my .emacs.d directory in my root directory.

I go to this link: http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/sr-speedbar.el
hit the download button, which I end up having to copy/paste the entire file, save it as sr-speedbar.el inside my .emacs.d directory.

~/.emacs.d now has sr-speedbar.el and my .emacs file has the below code:

```
  1 (add-to-list 'load-path "~/.emacs.d/evil")..
  2 (require 'evil)..
  3 (evil-mode 1)
  4 (require 'sr-speedbar)
```

~
~
so i close out emacs, open it back up and get this error:

```
Warning (initialization): An error occurred while loading `/Users/johncurry/.emacs':

File error: Cannot open load file, sr-speedbar

To ensure normal operation, you should investigate and remove the
cause of the error in your initialization file.  Start Emacs with
the `--debug-init' option to view a complete error backtrace.
```

so I $ emacs --debug-init

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (file-error "Cannot open load file" "sr-speedbar"$
  require(sr-speedbar)
  eval-buffer(#<buffer  *load*> nil "/Users/johncurry/.emacs" nil t)  ; Reading$
  load-with-code-conversion("/Users/johncurry/.emacs" "/Users/johncurry/.emacs"$
  load("~/.emacs" t t)
  #[0 "^H\205\262^@     \306=\203^Q^@\307^H\310Q\202;^@ \311=\204^^^@\307^H\312$
  command-line()
  normal-top-level()
```

sr-speedbar-open returns no match inside emacs.  Any idea how to get this wrong? I'm sure it's just me not understanding the instructions, but I need help with this.

Comment: The most likely scenario is that your `sr-speedbar.el` library is *not* in your `load-path`.  So you can either move `sr-speedbar.el` into a directory that is already in your `load-path`, or you can add the directory to your `load-path` where `sr-speedbar.el` is located.  There was a thread just a few minutes ago regarding adding a sub-directory to the `~/.emacs.d` directory -- e.g., create a directory named `lisp` and add it to your `load-path` and put your `sr-speedbar.el` file in there:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/24791753/2112489

Comment: I'm pretty sure I put it in my load-path, all other things I've installed are working. this is my emacs.d file :.emacs.d johncurry$ ls
Cask  emacs-nav-49 framemove.el
auto-save-list evil  init.el    it had sr-speedbar.el  but I removed it and went with the emacs-nav-49 which works fine.

Comment: @JohnCurry did you ever get this resolved? I'm having the same problem with emacs 24.4.1

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. When I checked the load path of emacs I found that the ~/.emacs.d directory wasn't part of the path.

You can check you load-path use the following command

`C-h v load-path RET`

To add the path I added the following to my .emacs file.

```
;; Add the ~/.emacs.d/lisp directory and all subdirectories to the load path of emacs
(let ((default-directory  "~/.emacs.d/lisp/"))
  (normal-top-level-add-subdirs-to-load-path))
```

I already had some files in the .emacs.d directory so I add a lisp directory so I wouldn't break anything.

I then reloaded my .emacs file and everything worked.
To reload your .emacs file use the following command

```
M-x load-file RET .emacs RET
```

source: https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/LoadPath