# Does .emacs.d belong to load-path?

Tags: emacs

My `.emacs.d/` contains the file load-directory.el, which, as its name suggests, provides the function load-directory (and, yes, it contains the statement `(provide 'load-directory)` too). I'd like load it at startup time, but the statement `(require 'load-directory)` returns this error:

```
File error: Cannot open load file, load-directory
```

What's wrong?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Note that you don't want to put `~/.emacs.d` itself in your load-path. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24779041/disable-warning-about-emacs-d-in-load-path

Comment: And to be clear, `~/.emacs.d` (`user-emacs-directory`) is not in the `load-path` by default.  That is the actual cause of your error.  In 24.4, there will be a warning if `user-emacs-directory` is in the `load-path`, so it's best to use a subdirectory.

Answer (score 6):

Use a sub-directory for your custom Lisp extensions, e.g. `~/.emacs.d/lisp/`, and add this directory to `load-path`:

```
(add-to-list 'load-path (locate-user-emacs-file "lisp/"))
```

Do **not** add `~/.emacs.d/` to your `load-path`.  For details, see [Disable warning about emacs.d in load path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24779041/disable-warning-about-emacs-d-in-load-path)

Answer (score 1):

No, .emacs.d does not belong into the load-path.

From the docstring:

> Directory beneath which additional per-user Emacs-specific files are
>   placed. Various programs in Emacs store information in this directory.

So this is a directory to which files are automatically written. It should therefore not contain your own files. Which means, if you add it to your load-path, you are probably doing something wrong.

The warning is a bit misleading. AFAICT, the problem is not the load-path per se, but that you do *not* want your own lisp files in that directory, because they could be overwritten.

Answer (score -1):

It looks like `load-directory.el` is not in your load path.  If it's it your `.emacs.d`, add it via:

```
(add-to-list 'load-path "path/to/.emacs.d")                  ; note: no trailing /
```

If `load-directory.el` itself holds all your `load-path` customizations, you can use the second, optional parameter of `require` to tell it which file name to use:

```
(require 'load-directory "path/to/directory/load-directory") ; note: no file extension needed
```

(And just in case: it should be `(provide 'load-directory)` and not `(provides ...)` in that file.)

Comment: Ok, thanks. But I really can't understand why the `user-emacs-directory` does not belongs to `load-path`.

Comment: You should **not** add `~/.emacs.d/` to `load-path`.