# Emacs24 auto-complete mode does not work

Tags: emacs

I have Emacs24, i want to use some modes like auto-complete.

Here is the thing, I installed 'linum' before and it's just working very well but others not working.

My .emacs file

```
(add-to-list 'load-path "/root/.scripts")
(require 'linum)
(global-linum-mode 1)

(require 'package)
(add-to-list 'package-archives '("melppa" . "http://melpa.milkbox.net/packages/"))
(package-initalize)

(add-to-list 'load-path "~/.emacs.d/")

(require 'auto-complete)
(require 'auto-complete-config)
(ac-config-default)
(require 'yasnippet)
```

auto-complete and yasnippet just doesn't working , i tried command 'auto-complete-mode' but its still same.

Any ideas ?

**EDIT : I installed it from source not from ELPA and it worked.**

Comment: When you open emacs does it give any error about init file?

Comment: No, there is no error. I tried to install it list-packages and select what i want and hit the install tab way but its still same.

Comment: 1. You need to actually *install* packages from MELPA before you can `require` them. 2. I notice that you're loading something from `/root`. Generally it's not a good idea to run as the `root` user.

Comment: only linum package is working which is interesting, othes just now working

Comment: @SashaValentine, `linum` is built into Emacs, so it's probably irrelevant that it's working.

Comment: it remembered something. I had Emacs23 and when i installed it it worked. Then i installed Emacs24 so linum might be irrelavant yes.

Comment: Side note: you generally shouldn't put `~/.emacs.d` in `load-path` ( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24779041/disable-warning-about-emacs-d-in-load-path).  Use `~/.emacs.d/lisp` instead.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue when I upgraded to Emacs 24. Have you tried running `M-x auto-complete`? When I did, I got an error message like the following:

gv-get: (popup-cursor ac-menu) is not a valid place expression

It turned out this was an already reported bug that can be fixed by recompiling your byte-code:

https://github.com/auto-complete/auto-complete/issues/222

https://github.com/auto-complete/auto-complete/issues/118

This solution worked for me:

```
$ find ~/.emacs.d/elpa -name '*.elc' | xargs rm
```

(to remove all compiled elisp in your elpa subdirectories)

... then, in an elisp interaction buffer, like scratch eval:

```
(byte-recompile-directory (expand-file-name "~/.emacs.d/elpa") 0)
```

... then re-start emacs.

Comment: i tried,"M-x auto complete ". Thanks for your attention but i uninstall emac23 and now im trying to re-install emacs24 and i'll try again because i'm almost sure this problem about crossing emacs23-emacs24 , here is the thing i can't uninstall emacs24 because i cannot see in package manager also i couldn't find where is its files like usr/bin.