# Emacs (24.4.1) will not open installed package

Tags: emacs

I am a newbie Emacs user, and have a problem when trying to install a new Emacs package. The package is https://github.com/tlh/workgroups.el.
I followed the file installation instructions in the accompanying README.md file: I copied the content of the "workgroup.el" into a new textfile with the same name, saved it to the same directory as my init.el file ("Put workgroups.el somewhere on your Emacs load path"), and added (require 'workgroups) to my init.el file ("Add this line to your .emacs file: (require 'workgroups)").

However, when saving and closing Emacs, and then opening my init file I get the
following error message

"File error: Cannot open load file, no such file or directory, workgroups "

Why doesn't Emacs recognize the new package?

Thanks in advance for any help : )

Comment: Start from making sure it is on the `load--path`, Type `C-h v` and then type `load-path`. Is the directory you put `workgroups.el` in the list ?

Comment: Thanks for your advice. I have put `workgroups.el` in my default directory, set by (setq default-directory `"C:/Users/espend/AppData/Roaming/.emacs.d/")`. And when typing `C-h v load-path`, I get, amongst others, this path: `"c:/Users/espend/AppData/Roaming/.emacs.d/elpa/ace-window-0.8.1/"`, which contains my default directory. So, is `workgroups.el` correctly placed to be made active by `(require `workgroups)` ?

Comment: I am not sure I understood correctly your question regarding the `default-path`, but `default-path` is just a buffer specific variable. What's important is that the `load-path` list contains the directory that has `workgroups.el`. Is `C:/Users/espend/AppData/Roaming/.emacs.d` (that's where you put `workgroups.el`, right ?) listed when you look at the value of your `load-path` ? Here's some more info [LoadPath](http://emacswiki.org/emacs/LoadPath)

Comment: no, `C:/Users/espend/AppData/Roaming/.emacs.d` is not listed explicitly, only directories below this directory, like  `"c:/Users/espend/AppData/Roaming/.emacs.d/elpa/ace-window-0.8.1/"` How can I add  `C:/Users/espend/AppData/Roaming/.emacs.d` explicitly?

Comment: Switch to a `*scratch*` buffer and type `(add-to-list 'load-path "C:/Users/espend/AppData/Roaming/.emacs.d")` and then type `C-x e`

Comment: In general Emacs has pretty good help system. If you type `M-x info-apropos` and then some keywords (in your case would be `library search`) it will you with the documentation.

Comment: Hi again :) now it works. I put `workgroups.el` in a subfolder to .emac.d (`C:/Users/espend/AppData/Roaming/.emacs.d/workgroups`) and then put `(add-to-list 'load-path "C:/Users/espend/AppData/Roaming/.emacs.d/workgroups")' into my `init.el` file. And now emacs recognizes the workgroup package. Thanks for your help !!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The directory where your init file lives (which is either your home directory or your `~/.emacs.d` directory) is not in your Emacs `load-path` by default, and should *not* be added to it. (Recent versions of Emacs will [complain](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24779041) if you do that.)

Instead place the new elisp library into a sub-directory named something like `~/.emacs.d/lisp`, and add *that* to your `load-path`, by adding the following to your init file:

```el
(add-to-list 'load-path (expand-file-name "~/.emacs.d/lisp"))
```