# How do I install zoom-frm.el in Emacs to get zoom by mouse-wheel?

Tags: emacs, window, zooming, font-size

> How do I install zoom-frm.el in Emacs to get zoom by mouse-wheel?

I want to install zoom-frm.el to Emacs, so I've downloaded the file and placed it inside .emacs.d.

Now the file says to place (require 'zoom-frm) inside init.el, however I get the error message "Cannot open file or directory zoom-frm".

Can someone provide some details on how to install this "addon" and set it up for proper behaviour to a novice?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

1. Put the library (file `zoom-frm.el`) and any libraries it requires (look in the file for "`(require`") inside a folder (directory) that is in your `load-path`.

   The libraries required by `zoom-frm.el` are: `frame-cmds.el` and `frame-fns.el`.  `zoom-frm.el` requires `frame-cmds.el` and `frame-cmds.el` requires `frame-fns.el`.  Put all three libraries in a folder that is in your `load-path`.

   (Library `frame-cmds.el` can also make use of libraries `strings.el` and `misc-fns.el`, but they are not strictly required.  Their `(require`...`)` expressions end in `nil t)`, which means that these libraries are "soft-required": nice to have but not strictly required.)
2. Put `(require 'zoom-frm)` in your init file, *after* the part of your init file where you define your `load-path`.
3. To get mouse-wheel zooming, follow the instructions in `zoom-frm.el`:

   ```
   (define-key ctl-x-map [(control ?+)] 'zoom-in/out)
   (define-key ctl-x-map [(control ?-)] 'zoom-in/out)
   (define-key ctl-x-map [(control ?=)] 'zoom-in/out)
   (define-key ctl-x-map [(control ?0)] 'zoom-in/out)
   (global-set-key (vector (list 'control mouse-wheel-down-event)) 'zoom-in)
   (global-set-key (vector (list 'control mouse-wheel-up-event))   'zoom-out))
   (global-set-key [S-mouse-1]    'zoom-in)
   (global-set-key [C-S-mouse-1]  'zoom-out)
   ;; Get rid of `mouse-set-font' or `mouse-appearance-menu':
   (global-set-key [S-down-mouse-1] nil)
   ```

---

See the Emacs manual, node [Load Libraries](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Lisp-Libraries.html) for more information, including about `load-path`.  You owe it to yourself to become familiar with this information, as it is basic information about requiring (loading) any library.

---

You can also install `zoom-frm.el` using the Emacs package system with MELPA.

Comment: Note that it isn't recommended to put `~/.emacs.d/` in the `load-path`.  The canonical place is `~/.emacs.d/lisp/`, but you could use any subdirectory.  See http://stackoverflow.com/a/24791753/245173.

Comment: Thank you @Drew - should I uncomment the commands in (3) in zoom-frm.el or paste them to init.el?
I can't seem to find (global-set-key (vector (list 'control mouse-wheel-down-event)) 'zoom-in)
(global-set-key (vector (list 'control mouse-wheel-up-event))   'zoom-out)) anywhere within zoom-frm.el?

Comment: Also, how to I press the key-binding like "control ?+" ? I try C-+, but nothing happens.

Comment: Yes, you can put that code (uncommented) in your init file. The sexp you cannot find is there, but I simplified it slightly for this post, as I assume your Emacs is at least version 22.

Comment: `C-+` means press and hold the `Control` key while you hit the `+` key (which is often `Shift` + the `=` key). The key bindings are `C-x C-+` and `C-x C--` (and `C-x C-0` to reset).

Comment: @Drew I can't see zoom-frm.el in MELPA. But, this is normal because it seems to me that your packages are no longer on MELPA. I don't see it in el-get either. It would be nice if it was there.

Comment: @RaoulHATTERER: Get my libraries from Emacs Wiki [Elisp Area](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs?action=elisp-area). `zoom-frm.el` is [here](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/download/zoom-frm.el). As for why my libraries are no longer on MELPA - see [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/emacs/comments/7vocqa/update_on_melpa_removing_emacswiki_packages_they/dtuhzmt/). Thx.

Comment: @Drew I had missed M-x el-get-emacswiki-refresh

Now all is OK with el-get.

Comment: @RaoulHATTERER: Good to hear things worked out OK. Thx for the confirmation.